# Return OpenCV image as response and display in browser

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I am encoding(base64) cv2 image and sending it as a response. Working with flask/python.

```py
img = cv2.imread("temp.png", 0)
new_encoded_img = base64.b64encode(img)
return Response(response=new_encoded_img, status=200, mimetype="text/plain")
```

Now I have to `setState` this image so that it can be rendered. How to do that? I am trying something like this.

```
this.setState({
            processedFile: ['data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/'+atob(response.data)]
        })
```

Comment: Response from server is like
data: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.."

Comment: atob() returns something in hexadecimal like "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u..."

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```py
with open("file.png", "rb") as file:
    return Response( b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + file + b'\r\n', mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

Or if you have `HttpResponse` implemented, you can directly render `"file.png"` using:

```py
with open("file.png", "rb") as f:
    return HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type="image/jpeg")
```